# Understanding a part of the proof of $\mu: \mathcal{A}\longrightarrow[0,\infty]$.

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, proof-explanation

I was reading the answer of this question :

[Convergence of measure sequences bounded by a finite measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589079/convergence-of-measure-sequences-bounded-by-a-finite-measure)

But I did not understand some parts in the proof of  **$\mu: \mathcal{A}\longrightarrow[0,\infty]$.**

First:  I did not understand why the $\epsilon$ in the definition of the limit is the same $\epsilon$ here "there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\mu(A)+\varepsilon=0$"?

Second: Also, I did not understand why "Thus for all $n>N$ we would have $\mu_n(A)<0$"?

Could anyone explain those parts for me, please? Also is not there an easier way of the proof?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun I have edited the title I am so sorry.

Comment: What is the difference between [tag:measure-theory] and [tag:general-measure-theory]?  Why did you create the second tag?

Comment: I think I should correct it to "General Measure Spaces" I am sorry @XanderHenderson

Comment: @XanderHenderson I corrected it

Comment: So, again, you have created a new tag without providing any guidance for it. What does the tag [tag:general-measure-spaces] do which isn't already done by other tags?  For example, I think that the [tag:measure-theory] tag pretty much categorizes your question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I just want to be able to differentiate between a question on Lebesgue measure and a question on general measure .... this was my intension of creating it .... for me measure theory mainnly about Lebesgue.

Comment: @Secretly If you tag the question [tag:measure-theory] and don't add the tag [tag:lebesgue-measure], you have done an excellent job of disambiguating your question. ;)

Comment: :))) by the way, do you have any answers to my questions? @XanderHenderson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since OP assumes $\mu(A)<0$ for some $A$, we can always choose $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $\mu(A)+ \epsilon_0=0$ (I used $\epsilon_0$ to avoid confusion)
2. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n(A) = \mu(A)$, by definition, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t for all $n>N$ , $|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)|< \epsilon$.

i.e:
$$-\epsilon \leq \mu_n(A)-\mu(A)<\epsilon,$$ for all $n>N$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this should hold for $\epsilon_0$ in (1) as well. Hence, $$-\epsilon_0 \leq \mu_n(A)-\mu(A)<\epsilon_0$$

From the rightmost inequality, we have $\mu_n(A) < \epsilon_0+ \mu(A) = 0$ for all $n>N$, which is a contradiction, since {$\mu_n$} is a sequnece of measures.