# Using the Weierstrass M-Test for proving countable additivity of a measure.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

Understanding a part of the solution given here:

[Convergence of measure sequences bounded by a finite measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589079/convergence-of-measure-sequences-bounded-by-a-finite-measure)

Here is the part that I do not understand:

3.) **$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(A_k)$.**

*Proof:* Since $\nu$ is a finite measure on $\mathcal{A}$, then for a countable collection of pairwise disjoint sets $\{A_i\}\in\mathcal{A}$ we have 
$$
\nu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right)=\sum_{i=k}^\infty\nu(A_k)<\infty.
$$
Now for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\mu_n(A_k)<\nu(A_k)$, so the Weierstrass M-Test tells us that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu_n(A_k)$ converges uniformly for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

**My Questions are:**

1- why is $\sum_{i=k}^\infty\nu(A_k)<\infty$? $\nu$ is a finite measure does not mean that the infinite series is finite, this is why I am not convinced with this statement. Could anyone help me understand this please?

2- Also, why is  $\mu_n(A_k)$ considered as a sequence of functions? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: $\nu$ is a finite measure and $\{A_k\}$ are disjoint sets.

Comment: Then what? how this leads to that the infinite sum is finite? by what theorem of Royden 4th edition? @d.k.o.

Comment: By definition, if $\mu(X) < \infty$, $\mu$ is called a 'finite' measure.

Comment: And {$A_k$} $\subset X$ so, $\cup A_k \subset X$. By montonicity, the result is obvious.

Comment: yes but I am speaking about the infinite sum. 1 is finite, but 1+1+1+.... is not a convergent series @SL_MathGuy

Comment: @Mathstupid since $\cup A_k \subset X$, $\nu(\cup A_k )< \nu(X) <\infty$

Comment: @SL_MathGuy is the union on $A_{k}$ finite or infinite?

Comment: @Secretly it's countably infinite( countable additivity of a measure )

Comment: Since $A_k$'s are disjoint, $\nu(\cup A_k)= \sum \nu(A_k) < \nu(X) < \infty$

Comment: And why we are sure that the countable union of $A_{k}$ is in $X$? @SL_MathGuy

Comment: $X$ is the measure space & each $A_k \subset X$

Comment: by sigma algebra definition ?@SL_MathGuy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question: $\sum \nu(A_k)=\nu (\cup_n A_k)<\infty$.

Second question. Define $f_n: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ by $f_n(k)=\mu_n(A_k)$. The series $\sum_k f_n(k)$ converges uniformly because it is dominated by the convergent series $\sum \nu(A_k)$.

Comment: is the union on $A_{k}$ finite or infinite?

Comment: I have the same questions as @Secretly

Comment: @Mathstupid By definition $\nu$ is a finite measure implies $\nu (E) <\infty$ for every set $E$ in the sigma algebra. In particular $\nu (\cup A_k) <\infty$.

Comment: is $\sum \nu (A_{k})$ a series of numbers?